# Could not find generator 'mongoid:config'. When rails generate mongoid:config

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.I've been trying generate mongoid.yml file to connect with mongodb. but im getting this error:

```
`Could not find generator 'mongoid:config'.
Did you mean?  mongoid:devise
Run `bin/rails generate --help` for more options.`
```

This is my Gemfile

```
 source "https://rubygems.org"
    git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
    
    ruby "3.1.3"
    
    
    
    gem 'mongoid'
    
    
    
    
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'figaro'
    gem 'haml-rails'
    gem 'haml'
    
    gem "bson"
    gem "moped", github: "mongoid/moped"`
    gem 'nokogiri'
    gem 'kaminari'
    gem 'rack-contrib'
    
    gem 'soulmate', require: 'soulmate/server'
    gem 'carrierwave'
    gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', require: 'carrierwave/mongoid'
    gem 'colorize'
    gem 'typhoeus'
    
    gem 'execjs'
    gem 'roo'
    gem 'addressable', require: 'addressable/uri'
    
    gem 'sass-rails'
    gem 'coffee-rails'
    gem 'uglifier'
    gem "passenger",require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"
```

I tried adding these to Gemfile. But not working.

`gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml', github: 'rails/activemodel-serializers-xml' gem "active_model_serializers", require: true gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml' gem 'active_model_serializers'`

I have noticed gem moped is kind of old for this version of mongoid. Please help if anyone

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`moped`](https://github.com/mongoid/moped) is an out of date (legacy) version of the [MongoDB Ruby Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ruby-driver/master/).

When you add the [`mongoid`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid) gem to your `Gemfile`, it will automatically pull in the version of the driver ([`mongo`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver)) that matches the dependency in the gemspec (ex: https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/v8.0.3/mongoid.gemspec#L41).

Removing `moped` from your `Gemfile` and re-running `bundle install` should do the trick ;)